# How do I calculate the time complexity of this algorithm?

Tags: time, complexity-theory

I have been trying to calculate the time complexity of this algorithm but I don't think that I am right.

Since it can't be n^2, I came up with a formula that goes O(n*(j*(1+j)*50), but I am still not sure enough.

```
for (int i = 1; i <= n; i++)
    for (int j = 1; j <= i ; j++)
        for (int k = 1; k <= 100; k++)
           cout << "Hello";
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is `O(n²)` indeed. The inner loop runs in constant time. It is the same as

```c
for(int i = 1;i<=n;i++)
  for(int j = 1;j<=i;j++) {
      cout << "Hello";
      cout << "Hello";
      cout << "Hello";
      cout << "Hello";
      /* repeats 96 mores times */
  }
```

More specifically, you can calculate the number of steps as

```
T(n) = 1 + 2 + 3 + ... + n
     = n * n(1 + n)/2
     = (n² + n)/2
```

Constants don't matter, so this function grows in `O(n² + n)` which is simply `O(n²)`.

Instead of unrolling the inner loop, you could multiply everything by 100, but this wouldn't change the complexity.

Comment: But the second loop, of index j, doesn't always have n cycles.

Comment: No, but the number of times the inner loop runs depends on `i`, which is `O(n)`. So you have `O(n)` times `O(n)`, which gives you `O(n²)`.

Comment: I don't agree, `i` changes from 1 to n, so it is not constant and can't be considered O(n).

Comment: That's how complexity analysis work. If you must, check for yourself. Write down the number of steps this function runs and plot the graph. It's `O(n²)`.

Comment: Ok, for i = 1, 1 cycle, for i = 2, 2 cycles, for i = 3, 3 cycles, etc. this is an arithmetic sequence starts with 1 and ends with n with n elements, whose sum is n*(n+1)/2.https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arithmetic_progression

Comment: Note that O(50n(n+1)) = O(n^2).

Comment: @AbdelAziz O(f(n)) is a set of functions asymptotically bounded above by f(n). Any function asymptotically bounded above by 50n(n+1) is also asympotically bounded above by n^2, and vice versa.

Comment: Can anyone tell me in a simple manner how O(n² + n) = O(n² )?

Comment: `O(50n·(n + 1))` = `O(n·(n + 1))` = `O(n² + n)` = `O(n²) + O(n)` = `O(n²)`

Comment: Why `O(n²) + O(n)` = `O(n²)`?

Comment: @giusti Good edit, though your first comment might be two sweeping. There are ways the inner loop might depend on i without being O(n), perhaps multiplicatively increasing toward i from 1, etc.

Comment: @AbdelAziz I said it as simply as it can be said above. Does that explanation make sense?

Comment: `O(n² + n)` = `O(n²)` because the `O` notation means "upper-bounded". It is saying that the function `n²` "can stay above" `n² + n` if you multiply the first by a constant. If you can, I suggest you check Thomas H. Cormen's "Introduction to Algorithms". This book explains really well how to do complexity analysis. It's an important subject and this book is definitely worth your while.

Comment: So lets come to a conclusion. The formula for the arithmetic sequence was right O(50n·(n + 1)) but when you multiply everything it ends up being O(n^2) because constants don't matter in time complexity.